# Unable to overwrite ffmpeg metadata

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am having some issues overwriting the metadata on video files using FFmpeg that already has metadata added to it previously(previous metadata also added by FFmpeg).

So I am using `ffmpeg -i path/to/video file -i /path/to/metadata -map_metadata 1 -codec copy path/to/output file` to merge the metadata file with the video file but if the video file has already been through this command once the new metadata won't stick, only the old ones remain. Is there a way of forcing the metadata to be overwritten by the new metadata file?

Most of what I have tried so far have only been making a metadata text file from scratch to see if there were some issues with the metadata I was extracting from the video file using `ffmpeg -i path/to/video file -f ffmetadata path/to/metadata`.
So far I haven't been able to find a lot about this online other than variations on this command, however, I think that is mostly due to the fact that I am not entirely sure what keywords I should search for.

Thanks for the read

Comment: Share full log of such an unsuccessful run. Also share full log of `ffmpeg -i output`

Comment: @Gyan Heres the log for the creation of the metadata file: https://pastebin.com/STngD2gh
And here's the log for the attempted "merge" of the video file after editing the metadata to add another chapter to it: https://pastebin.com/iG3qzrGh

Comment: All the important details related with the question should be INSIDE the question, not in the comments. You can Edit the Question as many times as you want.

Answer (score 2):

## Use the `-map_chapters` option.

`-map_chapters` copies chapters from an input file. It's zero-based (just like  `-map_metadata`). So, for your example, you'd specify `1`.

```sh
ffmpeg -i path/to/video file -i /path/to/metadata -map_metadata 1 -map_chapters 1 -codec copy path/to/output_file
```

Answer (score 0):

My head is still spinning around this topic, but here is what I found thanks to @t-mart.

As described in the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html),

```
-metadata[:metadata_specifier] key=value (output,per-metadata)

    Set a metadata key/value pair.

    An optional metadata_specifier may be given to set metadata on streams, chapters or programs. See -map_metadata documentation for details.

    This option overrides metadata set with -map_metadata
```

When you use `-metadata` you write to the Global metadata.

The problem I was facing (similar to yours) is that the metadata is well written the 1st time you write it, but any other attempt to edit/modify it fails. Apparently (I may be very mistaken here) because from Global it goes to the 1stChapter (or audio stream) but only when it doesn't exist, not after.

So the 2nd attempt writes only on Global and not in the chapter/stream, which is what `exiftool` seems to read.

You can play with the mapping options as explained by t-mart (nice examples in the documentation).

But I found a way that seems to write to Global and Chapters at the same time using the specifiers.

```
ffmpeg -y -i {file_in}   -metadata:s:0 VENDOR="My uncle"  -codec copy {file_out}
```

Output

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers

Input #0, ogg, from 'fx.ogg':
  Duration: 00:00:01.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 34 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      [...]
      VENDOR          : v1Tag

Output #0, ogg, to 'fxv12.ogg':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp
    Metadata:
      [...]
      VENDOR          : My uncle
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
size=       7kB time=00:00:01.67 bitrate=  34.6kbits/s speed=5.21e+03x    
video:0kB audio:7kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 6.422692%
```

And here is the output of `exiftool {file_out}`

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.80
File Name                       : fxv12.ogg
File Type                       : OPUS
File Type Extension             : opus
MIME Type                       : audio/ogg
Opus Version                    : 1
Encoder                         : Lavf57.83.100
Vendor                          : My uncle
```

Note: My solution may not work in your case (I am using ogg audio files only) but the key of the issue is that there are multiple metadata levels (global / per channel, etc.) and you may be writing to just one that then gets ignored (when reading with exiftool).

This command (from the documentation) provided similar results (you can add your  `-metadata` parameters, since they have priority).

```
# To do the reverse, i.e. copy global metadata to all audio streams:
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -map_metadata:s:a 0:g out.mkv
```